# How to sort Biblatex bibliography by type?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

I noticed the cool feature of Biblatex where you can subdivide bibliographies by using something like:

```
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[type=book,heading=subbibliography,title={Book Sources}]
\printbibliography[nottype=book,heading=subbibliography,title={Other Sources}]
```

However, the sort order in this case just depends on the normal sort order, and doesn't respect these sub-bibliographies; with the `numeric` style, this leads to stuff like:

### Books

[3] ...
[5] ...
[13] ...

### Non-books

[1] ...
[2] ...
[4] ...

Is there any way to change this behaviour? I tried the solution in [Biblatex - citing from two bibliographies with numeric-comp style (citing order)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577745/biblatex-citing-from-two-bibliographies-with-numeric-comp-style-citing-order), but it did not seem to change any sort orders when giving:

```latex
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \pertype{book}
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue={aa}]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Normally you don't actually need to influence sorting. It's usually enough to turn on `defernumbers=true,`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271751/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/586009/35864